# Django optional URL captured value for rest APIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For following Django code using django_rest_framework:

```
class PollMessageView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer

    lookup_url_kwarg = 'count'

    def get_queryset(self):
        count = self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)

        queryset = Message.objects.all()[:count]
        return queryset

urlpatterns = [
    path('poll_message/<int:count>', PollMessageView.as_view(), name="poll_message"),
]
```

How do I make the `count` parameter optional in the URL pattern? For example, if I visit `/poll_message/` without a count, it would still call the PollMessageView (and I can set a default number for `count` if it's missing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new path as ,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('poll_message/', PollMessageView.as_view(), name="poll_message-wo-count"),
    path('poll_message/<int:count>', PollMessageView.as_view(), name="poll_message"),
    
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# URLconf
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', views.page),
    path('blog/page<int:num>/', views.page),
]

# View (in blog/views.py)
def page(request, num=1):
    # Output the appropriate page of blog entries, according to num.
   ...
```

In detail reference - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#specifying-defaults-for-view-arguments

Answer (score -1):

You can [specify defaults for view arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#specifying-defaults-for-view-arguments), but the example on the website is for functional view, not sure how would that work for class based view or in this case, the rest framework class based view.

However, you can add another path with extra options to achieve the same thing

```
    path('poll_message/', PollMessageView.as_view(), {
        "count": 5
    }, name="poll_message"),
```